# create and save pure html file from php 'template'?

Tags: php, html

I am looking for a simple and effective way to create a pure html file based off a php file.  For instance, in template.php below the php would be inserting various portions of the page.  I want to save the page then as html removing all php code and leaving what was inserted by it... hopefully that makes sense... the output of template.php would be a better way to say it I guess.

First, I do not know if something like this is possible.  Second, is this the best way to go about something like this?

Before anyone starts screaming about security there will be ZERO user submitted / form submitted variables in this page.  My goal is to create a report from database values with the template which the user can then view/print/save off the server as pure html.  There will be no images only inline css.

**EDIT :**

This html only output of template.php needs to be saved on the server as its own file. The reason for the php 'template' is because I will be creating the vast majority of the page with php... but I only want to save its resulting output.

**template.php :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<!-- BEGIN HEAD -->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
    <meta content="<?php echo $desc; ?>" name="description" />
</head>
<!-- END HEAD -->


<!-- BEGIN BODY -->
<body>

... further html with php mixed in

</body>
<!-- END BODY -->

</html>
```

**Current solution :**

I did some further research and this is acting exactly how I want it to. Comments/suggestions welcome for it.

```
<?php

    ob_start();

    require_once('/home/test/public_html/template.php');

    if ( ob_get_length() > 0 )
    {
        $ssReport = ob_get_contents();
        file_put_contents('/home/test/public_html/test.html', $ssReport);
    }

    ob_end_clean();             

?>
```

Comment: Most browsers let you save a page to an html file. Could you just view the page in your browser, right click and do 'save as'?

Comment: Or use `curl URL > filename.html`

Comment: I need to create the file based off my php 'template' file and save it on my server.

Comment: You will find everything you need on PHP.net's filesystem directory http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use `REGEX` (Regular Expressions) to strip out all php-code.

The Expression `<\?php.*?\?>` can do that for you...

PHP-Example:

```
$tempateFile = file_get_contents('template.php');
$htmlPlain = preg_replace('/<\?php.*?\?>/si', '', $tempateFile);
```

If you allow "Shorthand Open Syntax" for php-files `<?` instead of `<?php` you should use the pattern `<\?(?:php)?.*?\?>` which will become `preg_replace('/<\?(?:php)?.*?\?>/si', '', $tempateFile);`

If you want to take a html-snapshot of your site(s) try this options:

1. use `wget` to grab a copy of your website (see [wget manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) or [wget tutorial](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/09/the-ultimate-wget-download-guide-with-15-awesome-examples/#more-1885))
2. use `curl` with a script to grab a copy of your website (see  [curl manual](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html) or 
   [curl tutorial](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html)
3. make a php-script which uses `file_get_contents($url)` to grab outputs of you specific public-available URL and store it with `file_put_contents(...)` to a html-file.

Comment: No, I need to create the html file on my server based off the php 'template' file.  The php will be adding information to it such as tables and other coming from my db.

Comment: So you want to capture your rendered OUTPUT of your page to a plain html-file like a "webcache will do" (or something like a html SNAPSHOT of your site)?

Comment: I guess you could say that... the php is going to be creating tables and other information from my database.  The output of the file (with the php additions) is what I need to save on my server as pure html.  I am trying to create a 'report' file on the fly, save it, then allow the user to download it off the server for archiving (which is why it must be pure html / the output of the php file).

Comment: see my edited answer with three options to snapshot your page.

Comment: #3 was similar to what I was looking for, but it copied the exact file contents of the php file including the php code.  I did some more research and have a working solution in my OP.  Comments/suggestions welcome.